# Criar nova DF baseada em uma coluna Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Sou novo em Python e Pandas eu tenho uma DF que com 3 colunas, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
SRC    Data1   Data2
AAA     180     122
BBB     168     121
CCC     165     147
DDD     140     156
EEE     152     103
AAA     170     100
CCC     166     112
DDD     116     155
EEE     179     119
```

O que eu preciso é que seja criada uma nova DF para cada valor que esteja em *SRC*, por exemplo:

DF_A

```
SRC    Data1   Data2
AAA    180     122
AAA    170     100
```

DF_B

```
SRC    Data1   Data2
BBB     168     121
```

e assim por diante em todos os valores que houverem em *SRC*, o que eu fiz foi criar uma DF com os valores únicos de *SRC*

```
pd.DataFrame(DataFrameBase.SRC.unique())
```

mas não sei se isso vai realmente me ajudar!

Já agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode dar o distinct no campo `SRC` com o comando `unique` e apos isto montar os dataFrames que precisa por exemplo:

```
uniques = df.SRC.unique()
print(uniques)
dataFrames = []

for unique in uniques:
    data = df[df.SRC == unique]
    dataFrames.append(data)

print("Tamanho: " + str(len(dataFrames)) + '\n')

for data in dataFrames:
    print(data)
    print('\n')
```

Após o distinct eu percorro cada item montando o conjunto correspondente e adiciono em um array.

Mas se você precisa apenas do SRC `AAA` e `BBB` por exemplo você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
df_a = df[df.SRC == 'AAA']
df_b = df[df.SRC == 'BBB']

print(df_a)
print('\n')
print(df_b)
```

Comment: Cara ta lindo! Pra fechar, como que eu faria pra ao invés de imprimir salvar novas DF?

Comment: se vc utilizou o array, cada posição do array tem um dataFrame, ou se usou apenas o `df_a` e o `df_b` os dois são dataFrames, no dataFrame você pode salvá-los como `csv` ou `xlsx` pelo comando `to_csv` ou `to_excel` por exemplo: `df_a.to_csv('df_a.csv')` ou `df_b.to_excel('df_a.xlsx')`, ele vai salvar o arquivo na mesma pasta onde o app está, mas você também pode passar o path completo por exemplo `C:/.../file.cls`

Comment: E como eu faria para salvar os arrays? tentei o .to_csv mas não deu certo, sei que estou perguntando muito, mas estou começando agora com pandas.

Comment: imagina, o array voce vai precisar fazer o forEach mais antes é melhor criar um indice para nomear os arquivos: `index = 0` ai vc faz o for `for data in dataFrames:` agora dentro do for vc vai passar por todos os dataFrames, eles estão armazenados em data, agora voce consegue fazer `data.to_csv('dataFrame_' + str(index) + '.csv')` apos esta linha você precisa incrementar o indice para o proximo arquivo `index += 1`

Comment: cara **MUITO OBRIGADO**